# How do I specify the block object / predicate required by NSDictionary's keysOfEntriesPassingTest?

Tags: cocoa, macos, grand-central-dispatch

For learning (not practical -- yet) purposes, I'd like to use the following method on an NSDictionary to give me back a set of keys that have values using a test I've defined. Unfortunately have no idea how to specify the predicate.

```
NSDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
- (NSSet *)keysOfEntriesPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

Let's say for example all my values are NSURLs, and I'd like to get back all the URLs that are on port 8080. Here's my stab at coding that -- though it doesn't really make sense to me that it'd be correct:

```
NSSet * mySet = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                 if( [[obj port] isEqual: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8080]]) {
                     return key;
                 }]
```

And that's because I get back the following compiler error:

> incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(struct objc_object *, struct objc_object *, BOOL *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, struct objc_object *, BOOL *)'

What am I missing? I'd appreciate a pointer at some docs that go into more detail about the "Block object" that the *predicate* is supposed to be.

Thanks!

---

And this is the code that works:

```
NSSet *mySet = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
{
  if ([[obj port] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 8080]])
     return YES;
   else
     return NO;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for question / answer; I just fixed a typo in "the code that works" section above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that your block must return a `BOOL`, rather than `id`. Check the docs. I suspect you are expected to return `YES` if the key/obj pair passes the desired test.

Comment: Hey what do you know.. Those log messages, are useful! Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that you will run into the same error is you return a bool.  BOOL and bool are similar but not identical; and this is one case where they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 7):

A little expansion on Barry's answer....

A block is just like a function pointer with one key difference.  A block will infer the return type from the return statements contained within *or* it will give an error message like the one you said (the LLVM compiler's error should be a bit more reasonable).

When you wrote:

```
NSSet * mySet = [myDict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                 if( [[obj port] isEqual: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8080]]) {
                     return key;
                 }]
```

Consider that as a function:

```
BOOL bob(id key, id obj) {
    if( [[obj port] isEqual: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8080]]) {
        return key;
    }
}
```

See the problem?  There is a code path that doesn't return a value and, thus, the compiler would complain.